# token requests always results in "Authorization code is invalid."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, oauth-2.0, beatsmusic

Seems no matter what I do, requesting a token I always get the `Authorization code is invalid.` response. I have tried this both in Ruby code and via Curl.

```
curl -X POST https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/oauth2/token -d client_secret=SECRET -d client_id=MYID -d redirect_uri=http://foo.example.com/auth/beats_oauth2 -d code=rjmsqtgntc5k6s8jhdawpu4c
```

results in:

```
{"code":"InvalidCredentials","message":"Authorization code is invalid."}
```

Same results for the RoR code.

any suggestions would be great as I have been working on this for a few days!

thanks!
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the redirect URL on the getToken request was wrong. The callback I set in the Beats Music API config was "/auth/beats_oauth2/callback" but in the my code and the above example Curl I only had "/auth/beats_oauth2". I can't believe I looked at that a million times... Of course the invalid access code error message made me think it was not related to the redirect url. But that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your authorization code has expired? I see [here](https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/tutorials/How_to_Refresh_your_Access_Token) that they are only valid for 1 hr and then need to be refreshed. Instructions to do so are also at that link.

Comment: the RoR code is making the token request immediately and the Curl I'm doing within a minute (enough time to cut the Auth Code and paste it into the command line. .     can't imagine it's expiring that quick..

Answer (score 0):

The example from the [docs](https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/getting_started/Web_Server_Applications) also shows a `-d grant_type=authorization_code` parameter being sent. Have you tried it with that param included?

Comment: Yes..  I have tried it with and without..     I don't think it's a required param..   missing any of the others produces a Missing Parameter exception..